# android User-space exception detected!

Tags: android, asp.net, nullpointerexception

Estoy tratando de conectar mi android app con un web service en ASP.Net para actualizar datos. El tema es que, por lo que entiendo, la conexión se establece, pero el `responseBody` retorna vacío y se crea el `ResultadoObject` a `null`. ¿Estoy en lo cierto? ¿Alguna posible pista de la causa o solución? Gracias de antemano.

Uso `AsyncHttpClient`()

Depurando recibo estos valores:

> str = "", responseBody = {byte[0]@5870}, statusCode: 200

```
client.post(url, requestParams, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler(){
  @Override
  public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
      System.out.println("onSuccess");
      String str = null;
      try {
          str = new String(responseBody, "UTF-8");
      }
      catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
      if (str != null)
      {
          ResultadoObject resultado = null;
          try {
             resultado = new ResultadoObject(new JSONObject(str));
          } catch (JSONException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
          if (resultado.Flag != 0 && resultado.IDMantenimiento != 0)
          {
             loading = false;
             progressDialog.dismiss();
             cambios = true;
             getMantenimiento(resultado.IDMantenimiento);
          }
```

> User-space exception detected!
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int
>   com.model.ResultadoObject.Flag' on a null object reference at
>   com.activities.MantenimientoEditarActivity$7.onSuccess(MantenimientoEditarActivity.java:791)
>   at
>   com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:351)
>   at
>   com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler$ResponderHandler.handleMessage(AsyncHttpResponseHandler.java:510)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)"

Comment: Comprueba que requestParams sea distinto de null

Comment: @pablo gracias por tu rápida respuesta. requestParams contiene los valores correctos...es lo que me extraña a mí. También los parámetros coinciden con los del servicio

Comment: Estás completamente seguro de que tu WS funciona correctamente y devuelve datos?

Comment: Le voy a dar otra vuelta al WS y comento, gracias

Comment: @Juan   resultado = new ResultadoObject(new JSONObject(str)); esto obtiene un valor null, debes revisar que contiene str . Como es null el valor de resultado, genera un error en este punto: resultado.Flag

Answer (score -1):

El problema en realidad es que estas obteniendo un valor null para resultado:

```
   resultado = new ResultadoObject(new JSONObject(str));
```

esto debido a que str probablemente no tiene valor o no es un objeto Json, para esto debes revisar el resultado de la petición.

Para evitar el error agrega la validación `resultado != null` :

```
...
...
      if (resultado != null && resultado.Flag != 0 && resultado.IDMantenimiento != 0)
          {
             loading = false;
             progressDialog.dismiss();
             cambios = true;
             getMantenimiento(resultado.IDMantenimiento);
          }
...
...
```

Comment: **CP Cuando se califique con -1, es bueno para el sitio se indique la razón**, esto para mejorar la pregunta, eliminarla o si existen argumentos platicar sobre el tema.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta  @Elenasys ! No sé quién le habrá dado -1, yo todavía no tengo 125 de reputación